# How to determine the maximum stack size limit?

Tags: java, size, stack, limit, max

I want to determine the maximum size of the stack programmatically from within Java (the size set by -Xss). How do I do this?

Alternatively, as my Java module also uses a native code module, I would be able to do this via JNI; but how?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but this may be a good starting piont.  http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=411

Comment: If there's a way to do it, apart from parsing the arguments AlexR pointed out, I don't think it's through JMX.  By the way... you are using the Oracle/Sun JVM aren't you?

Comment: I already saw the ODI page.
The code needs to work on all platforms.
It should not rely on parsing the input arguments, because in this case I can not figure out the value in case no stack size arguments are given.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()` to access all arguments passed to VM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not best practice but certainly straight-forward: I'd write a recursive method counting up a value, recurring until java.lang.StackOverflowError and look at the counter.

```
public class Test
{

static void recur(AtomicInteger start)
{
    start.incrementAndGet();
    recur(start);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    AtomicInteger start=new AtomicInteger(0);
    try
    {
        recur(start);
    }
    catch (java.lang.StackOverflowError e)
    {
        /**/
    }
    System.out.println(start);

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of this option. However, I was looking for a way which uses only a few CPU cycles because I need to determine the free stack size for a thread which someone else has created.

Comment: It seems that this is not a reliable method to determine the maximum for nested method calls. In tests this produces a different result each time the program is run reaching from values around 10,000 to 43,000.