# How do we get memory information regarding the stack space and the PermGen space?

Tags: java, memory

Hi all I was wondering how do we get the size of the memory allocated per stack (e.g. -Xss512k),

and the size of the memory allocated to the PermGen space (e.g. XX:MaxPermSize=256m) ?

I've looked into

1. [java.lang.Runtime.totalMemory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory%28%29)
2. [java.lang.Runtime.freeMemory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29)
3. [java.lang.Runtime.maxMemory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory%28%29)

but the functions only return information about the heap space.

How do we query information about the stack space and the PermGen space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your journey starts at [MemoryManagerMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryManagerMXBean.html) where you can find all the memory pools; after that, ask [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html) to find out details about a given pool.

The simplest way would be,

```
List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memoryPoolMXBeans = 
                                       ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
for (MemoryPoolMXBean pool: memoryPoolMXBeans) {
    out.println("pool: " + pool.getName());
    out.println("    type: " + pool.getType());
    out.println("    usage: " + pool.getUsage());
    out.println();
}
```

Also, take a look at [How to determine the maximum stack size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487767/how-to-determine-the-maximum-stack-size-limit) — they have a way to get the parameters passed to JVM.